# Sqlite pviot Add a count row with totals

Tags: sqlite

I am sure first time this question is been asked in this group.

Using sqlite i would like to do pivot display with total count in each row bottom. And i am able to do pivot table but total count is failed to do so .

**CURRENT SQL QUERY:**

```js
SELECT
    number as no,
 outl as name,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1S,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1M,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T,
 (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1W,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN saturday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1SA,
 (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK2S,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK21M,
 (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3S,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3M,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3T,
 (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3W,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3T,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN saturday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3SA
  
FROM labels51 group by number
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**
[image]

Expected: on bottom i need total count of each row like **case when WK1S = sunday then count(WK1S) and case when WK1M = monday then count (WK1M) ....** ..

**[image: RESULT working fine based on new suggestion.]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
SELECT
    number as no,
 outl as name,
  
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1S,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN monday  ELSE 0 END) AS WK1M,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T,
 (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1W,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN saturday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1SA,
 (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK2S,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK21M,
 (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3S,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3M,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3T,
 (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3W,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3T,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN saturday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3SA
  
FROM labels51 
     
  UNION   all
  SELECT "GRAND TOTAL",
 NULL ,
 
   
   COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND sunday LIKE "%sunday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1S,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND monday LIKE "%monday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1M,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND tuesday LIKE "%tuesday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1T,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND wednesday LIKE "%wednesday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1W,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND thursday LIKE "%thursday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND saturday LIKE "%saturday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1SA,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" AND sunday LIKE "%sunday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK2S,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" AND monday LIKE "%monday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK2M,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND sunday LIKE "%sunday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3S,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND monday LIKE "%monday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3M,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND tuesday LIKE "%tuesday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3T,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND wednesday LIKE "%wednesday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3W,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND thursday LIKE "%thursday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND saturday LIKE "%saturday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3SA

  FROM labels51
```